# Another literacy test question

Tags: word, puzzle-history

This comes from the 1964 Louisiana literacy test for eligibility to vote.

> Write every other word in this first line and print every third word
>   in same line (original type smaller and first line ended at comma) but
>   capitalize the fifth word that you write.

Comment: These . . . aren't really puzzles.  The first one already is getting downvoted into oblivion.  I'd recommend deleting this one before it costs you more rep.

Comment: @Rubio You may be right. Having said that, the first one definitely has a different answer to the ones that have been given.  And the answer to this one is not at all obvious.

Comment: @Rubio The final one I was going post was "Draw five circles that one common inter-locking part" which is question 25 on the test.

Comment: @Lembik FYI, the [key is here - first PDF](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ms-android-att-us&biw=360&bih=615&q=state+of+louisiana+literacy+test+answers&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK5Lu3-aXRAhVItY8KHXvhCYIQ1QIIeSgA#xxri=0)

Comment: @Techidiot Yes. But I also think the questions are sufficiently ambiguous that other answers are acceptable too.  That's why I thought it might be interesting here.

Comment: @Lembik: Actually, that would make it *un*acceptable here. Puzzles should have one answer; anything else runs the risk of being closed as off-topic for being too broad.

Comment: @Deusovi Does that also apply to puzzle-history where the original puzzle was also ambiguous? One can of course rephrase the question as "How many answers can you find?" I suppose.

Comment: @Lembik: Depends on the question being asked. If it's "what is the answer?", then the question would still be too broad. But questions about the inventor, the original publication, the name, etc. are (probably) perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write every other word in this first line and print every third word in same line (original type smaller and first line ended at comma) but capitalize the fifth word that you write.

> *<sub>Write other in first and every word the,</sub>*
> **other this and third The**

The trick here is

> you get another set of instructions

Or of course it is just

> every other word in this first line and print every third word in same line (original type smaller and first line ended at comma) but capitalize the fifth word that you write.

Comment: What do you do with the instructions in brackets? That is "(original type smaller and first line ended at comma)".

Comment: @Lembik edited to correct.

Comment: What an amazingly sensible way to test eligibility to vote :) (Sarcasm alert.)

Comment: But... the obvious answer is to write **every other word in this first line and print every third word in same line (original type smaller and first line ended at comma) but capitalize the fifth word that you write.**

Comment: @Rubio oh yeah I'll add that too (grats on 9k btw!)

Comment: Shouldn't it the the 'and' that is capitalised? That's the fifth written word after all. Also, shouldn't that last 'the' of your first line be 'same'?